# Grails: hasMany dependencies

Tags: grails, has-many

I have two Grails classes with a hasMany dependency:

```
class Author {

String name

static hasMany = [books: Book] 
}
```

I generated the controller with scaffolding its running and works. But is there a way to gernate a book within the the author controller? So there i can generate a author and some book without changing the view? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The built in scaffolding templates for Grails do not have this ability. However, you can use the Grails command `install-templates` and modify/enhance the templates to have this ability.

Using this command the following directories and contents will be added to your project:

```
src
   templates
       artifacts
       scaffolding
       war
```

The templates within the "scaffolding" directory are where you want to make your changes/enhancements.

So, in short, no, there is no out of the box functionality for this, but you can add it on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Is there any Grails Plugin that can solve that problem?

Comment: Nope, but you could author one! (: